# inspecting 2D array inner type

Tags: c++

I am trying to check if the type of an array element is a specific type. See the following.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using arr = std::int32_t[2][2];

    std::cout << std::is_same_v<decltype(std::declval<arr>()[0][0]), std::int32_t> << std::endl;
}

>>> 0
```

Why is the above code printing zero? I also tried getting some other data about the type. See the following.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main() {
    using arr = std::int32_t[2][2];

    std::cout << typeid(decltype(std::declval<arr>()[0][0])).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(decltype(std::declval<arr>()[0][0])) << std::endl;
}

>>> i
>>> 4
```

As can be seen above, the type is an integer and 4 bytes, just like an `std::int32_t`. What am I doing incorrectly? Am I misinterpreting the `typeid` output? Thanks.

I'm using g++ 12.1.0 compiling for c++ 17.

Comment: Why `std::int32_t` vs. just `int32_t`?

Comment: @tadman I just picked a random convention.

Comment: It is certainly random.

Comment: @tadman Sure. It also certainly doesn't matter... especially regarding this question.

Comment: I'm just making an observation, nothing more. Don't mind me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the expression is lvalue reference to `std::int32_t`. You can use `remove_reference` to get the expected `std::int32_t`:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using arr = std::int32_t[2][2];

    std::cout << std::is_same_v<decltype(std::declval<arr>()[0][0]), std::int32_t&&> << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(std::declval<arr>()[0][0])>, std::int32_t> << std::endl;
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/8o9Yr9Kan)

Concerning your usage of `typeid`, first note that the `name` is implementation defined, it could be anything, you shouldnt assume that the `name` for `int32_t` is `i` (it is, but nevertheless ;).

Then (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) on the `typeid` operator):

> (1) Refers to a std::type_info object representing the type type. If type is a reference type, the result refers to a std::type_info object representing the referenced type.

You are comparing two somewhat unrelated tools. `typeid` is to infer the type of an polymorphic object. For that usually reference or not does not matter, you just care about the dynamic type of the object. `decltype` on the other hand is to deduce the type of an expression where references do matter.

Comment: I see thanks. Shouldn't `typeid(...).name()` have returned `i&` and not just `i`?

Comment: @Jaan see the edit, no

Comment: Got it. Appreciate the answer. Thanks